# Java Creating a method that accepts an integer array and a integer variable

Tags: java

Can anybody help me create a method that holds an integer array and integer variable?

Basically I am trying to write this program where the user enters one number less than 20, say for example 3, and the program returns double of 3 down to a double of 2 and to a double of 1. So 3 = 6, 2 = 4, 1 = 2. I am new to java been trying to write this program all day and have gotten nowhere. Any help is appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
public class DoubleDown {
public static void main(String[] args) {

   Scanner user_input = new Scanner( System.in );          //This recieves the users input
    int num = Integer.parseInt(user_input.next());          // and converts it to an integer.

    for(int i = num; i > 0; i--) {                         //Loop to count down from user's input
        System.out.println(i * 2);                         //and double it.
    }

}
```

}

Comment: sorry i should have clarified the method should be in a new class